# can the blue bird next to link's house be caught?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

When you start the game there's a "punching bag" of sorts that you can strike with a sword. Do so enough times and a blue bird flies away. Is it possible to catch this bird? And if so is there any point to catching him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Punching bag" is a [scarecrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarecrow), which obviously fails at its job. Apart from staying on the failcrow till you've dealt enough damage, the bird acts the same as your usual critters in the rest of the game: it escapes if you get too close.

The only flying things you can catch in *A Link between Worlds* are

- fairies
- bees
- golden bees
- apples (well, they fell at some point from some tree).